# How to get live instance of interface controller in watchOS?

Tags: swift, swift2, watchos-2, watchos

In my `ExtensionDelegate`, I'd like to get an instance of one of my interface controllers. I'm using a page-based navigation.

For example, I can do this in `iOS` like this:

```
if let controller = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[1] as? TimesController {
 controller.myVariable = nil
}
```

How can I do this in `watchOS`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  There's no concept of a page view controller on watchOS which would hold an array of interface controllers.

Since you can't pass another context in preparation for a page segue, you would need to update that specific interface controller's property within its `willActivate()` method:

```
override func willActivate() {
    super.willActivate()
    myVariable = ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the following code:

```
guard let interface = WKExtension.shared().rootInterfaceController as? InterfaceController else {
    return
}
```

Comment: Hi @smargo and welcome to Stack Overflow!  Generally we discourage code-only answers.  Could you maybe add a written English explanation of why/how this solves the problem?

Comment: Hi welcome to Stack Overflow.

A high quality answer should include a description of how your answer solves the original question

Answer (score 2):

As of Watch OS 4+, we can use `visibleInterfaceController`:

```
WKExtension.shared().visibleInterfaceController
```

---

> #### visibleInterfaceController
>
> Returns the last visible interface controller.
>
> <sub>Ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkextension/2868459-visibleinterfacecontroller</sub>